# Magento 2.1.10: Sort by Special Price doesn't working

Tags: magento-2.1, query, product-sorting

I'm working on category page, and try to sort the products collection by Special Price. 
I've override `setCollection()` of `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar`
[image]

And the result is the only sort for Normal price (not including Special Price):
[image]

So my solution is Left Join with `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table (this table is using for store Special Price, also store Normal Price as well, 149.0000 is normal price, and 120.0000 is special price).
[image]
[image]

And I print the query, and got this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.`value` AS `special_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='127'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` ON e.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id WHERE (attribute_id = 78 or attribute_id = 77) AND (catalog_product_entity_decimal.store_id = 0) GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `special_price` desc, `price` desc
```

But with this, the `GROUP BY` affected before `ORDER BY`, and ruin my result.
Its remove the 120.0000 and only show the 149.0000 in query result

If I remove the `GROUP BY`, it will show both, but the Magento code will error with "Already exists Entity Id".

If there is any way to make `GROUP BY` go after `ORDER BY`? Or better way to solve the problems?
 Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no need for coding. You can add sort by special price in frontend by simply changing **`Used for Sorting in Product Listing`** value to Yes in special_price attribute.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora i've tried as you said, but its not working, i've clear cache as well.

Comment: Hello @fudu did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @IsuruDilshan sorry, i don't find anything yet.

Comment: Hello @fudu I have tested this in 2.4.1 and  `this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');` is working as expected. But on the listing page, it shows final_price instead of minimal_price. For the sorting, they use a minimal price. This is the reason why the front end got confused. So I create a plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\Product and return MinimalPrice for afterGetSpecialPrice. That shows the correct value in the front end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IsuruDilshan no problems, i'm happy if that helped you.